# Самый простой браузер. Только Загрузка страниц и поддержка JS

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, браузер

Искал в интернете браузер, который может ТОЛЬКО загружать Web-страницы и поддерживающий JS. Никаких плагинов, без поддержки нескольких вкладок. Но таковых я не нашел. Простите, и спасибо заранее.

Comment: А зачем? Какую задачу вам надо решить?

Comment: Я хотел бы использовать Windows консольную команду copy /b ... app.exe чтобы "скомпилировать" html страницу, с минимальным размером исходного файла. Если есть другие способы пишите. Спасибо

Comment: В винде есть какой-то веб-вью который использует IE, так что наверное можно вообще без браузера обойтись.

Comment: Почитаю о об этом. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Lynx - самый простой и облегченный браузер) Правда он только текстовый =\

https://lynx.browser.org/